# How to append element after thumbnail

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, plugin-development, loop

Hey I just wanted to know how to add an element after the first thumbnail image in my loop. Basically I want an HTML div tag inserted after the first image in my post. Anyone know how to do that in WordPress, heres what I have:

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                  $post_pic  = get_the_post_thumbnail();
                  $post_pic .= '<div></div>';
                  return $post_pic;
?>
```

Comment: is this within a function? what are you `return`ing to?

Comment: Yeah I'm doing this within the main loop in default.php, I want to change the content to ad a div after every first image in the content, then return and display that content with the newly added divs just after the first image

Comment: I think you would need to use `echo $post_pic;` and add a closing `}` -  as @Milo points out this is just an if statement and not a function so it has nothing to return to. `get_the_post_thumbnail()` does just that - it doesn't echo it for you like `the_post_thumbnail()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to target the first item you can define a variable `$first_round=true` before you start the loop. Inside the loop, towards the end, you do `$first_round=false`. So this variable is only true the first time you go through the loop and you can add

```
if ($first_round) echo '<div>...</div>'
```

right after your call to `the_post_thumbnail()`.